# Phonegap show login page once while installing

Tags: cordova

I'm currently working on a phonegap project which requires me to show the login once while installing the App. Can anybody suggest me a good approach to this??
Your contribution is Appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can u be more specific. Showing login once is too broad, state your scenario more clearly.

Comment: thanks alot for your response, What i actually want to achieve is just that Login form should only appear while installing the App. Once Login succesfull the login form shouldn't appear again, Except the person reinstall the App

Comment: Ok , u need a Database for that (WebSql database P.S it has enough storage to keep user app info in it.), and after once user has registered store the id and password and everytime he opens up the app check its value , so onDeviceReady() do that operation.Hope it Helps. Put Some Code and Ask , So that u could get better guidance .

Comment: No that not what i want , I already have a local storage which stores user account detail and get it back for more operation. I want to restrict the login page such a way that it will only be visible on installation, once the installation is completed it hidden and next time user load the app it should just load directly to App menu. Thanks Once Again.

Comment: Ok , then onDeviceReady check if the user has registered and has valid credentials which he added during registeration and then redirect him to menu page .

Comment: can you show me a example that implement this??

Answer (score 0):

```
var db ;
var app={
initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", function(){ console.log("---    paused ---"); isAppPaused = true;}, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        this.initializeDB();
        this.checkConfig(db);
    },
    initializeDB:function(){
          if(window.sqlitePlugin !== undefined) {
            console.log('opening sqlite DB ');
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("MyDB");
        } else {
            console.log('opening Web SQL DB ');
            db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        }   
    },
    checkConfig:function(db){
    //In here u query your table for user registeration ;
    //if its true, navigate on to menu page.

    }

};
app.initialize();
```